# Tracking dynamic events in Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement dynamic events in my platform to trackearlos.

My question is:

**For generating these events and who are trackeados in Google Analytics to put the push of the "onclick" to do something else?**

I put this in my links:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Baby\'s First Birthday']);">Play</a>
```

That alone should of tracked at me in Google Analytics. I'm in the category VIDEOS PLAY action is and the name is BABY'S FIRST BIRTHDAY not?

Or do I have to do something else?

The idea is that it will automatically put those goals in google analytics or do I need from Google Analytics in panel enlist hand sequence each event / goal?

Comment: Yes, providing you have the `_gaq` array set up in your code then that should work. If you use Firefox install OmniBug - that will allow you to see the requests you make to Google re. Analytics.

Comment: @cbeneyto If you find the solution please post it as Answer so that other users can know the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

[crmpicco](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/14473/crmpicco) says:

Yes, providing you have the `_gaq` array set up in your code then that should work. If you use Firefox install OmniBug - that will allow you to see the requests you make to Google re. Analytics.